# Change back to initial value of rotation?

Tags: xna

I have a sprite that I can rotate and I wonder if there is a way to change the rotation back to the initial value?

Comment: `sprite.Rotation = 0;`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? By initial value I assume you mean default. In that case it's 0.

Comment: Thanks! At first I didn't thought that it worked, but I had missed a call to a property to set this value.

Comment: @Tharwen Make it an answer and we'll get this question wrapped up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the rotation of the sprite to 0:

```
sprite.Rotation = 0;
```

Comment: This answer is so short... it feels like cheating.